# C Code slower on Windows than on Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, performance, portability

i'm working on a project that will have builds for Windows and Linux, 32 and 64 bits.
This project is based on loading strings for a text file, process it and write results to a SQLite3 database.

On linux it reaches almost 400k sequences per second, compiled by GCC without any optimization. However on Windows it stucks in 100k sequences per second, compiled on VS2010 without any optimization.

I tried using optimizations in compilers but nothing changed.

Is this right? C code on Windows runs slower?

EDIT:

I think i need to be more clear on some points.
I made tests with code optimization enabled AND disabled. Performance didn't changed, probably because my program's bottleneck is the time wasted reading data from HD.

This program takes benefits of parallel computing. There a queue where a thread queues processed data and another dequeue to write in the SQLite database. This way i don't think there is any performance lose from this.

Comment: GCC on Linux is rumored to be quite a good compiler (when you ask it to optimize, with e.g. `gcc -O2`); and Linux is a quite good kernel.

Comment: We really need to see what call are you using. But normally it shouldn't differ that much. The machine code runs on the same speed on every OS. however in some cases compilers output different machine codes that run on different speeds.

Comment: It will depend greatly on what the code is doing and, more importantly, how it does it.  For example, if you are doing a pile of posix API stuff, then there might be extra overhead to interface with Win apis.

Comment: Windows should not be slower by that margin, and _nothing_ changing with optimisation turned does not sound quite right. Without optimizations, it's very compiler dependent what they consider being optimizations and thus disabling, but with optimizations turned on, both compilers should do a fairly good job.

Comment: Did you run the code on the same machine (i.e. dual boot) ?

Comment: Have you tried to measure the speed without saving the results on the DB?

Comment: Well, if your code runs the same speed optimized and unoptimized then you either measure it wrong, or the code's speed is completely irrelevant as all time is spent in disk i/o or something similar

Comment: If optimization does not affect run time, you likely have an I/O bottleneck. I do not use Windows myself, but I understand VS2010 `sprintf()` in particular is extremely slow (addressed in SP1). String handling and (complex) I/O in standard libraries is not optimized for speed, instead they target correctness and portability. I guess you're using standard I/O, and were just bitten by the particular slowness of VS2010 standard I/O and string handling.

Comment: While not directly relevant to this question, I checked the speed of float parsing using embedded GNU C. It shows how tricky/sensitive I/O efficiency is. At full optimization on my computer, `fscanf()` reads 3 million floats/second, `fread()`+`strtof()` 5 million, and unistd.h `read()`+`parse()` 10 million floats/second; `parse()` is a naive character-by-character parser that gives correct answers for finite (normal) floats, but does not support exponent format. The effect optimization has on the `fscanf()` version is just 4%, about 20% on `strtof()`, and about 50% for the custom parser.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this right? C code on Windows runs slower?

No. C doesn't have speed. It's the implementations of C that introduce speed. There are implementations that produce fast behaviour (generally "compilers that produce fast machine code") and implementations that produce slow behaviour for both Windows and Linux.

It isn't just Windows and Linux that are significant here, either. Some compilers optimise for specific processors, and will produce slow machine code for any other processors.

> I tried using optimizations in compilers but nothing changed.

Testing speed without optimisations enabled makes no sense. However, this does tend to indicate that *something else* is slow. Perhaps the implementation that produced the library files for SQLite3 client in Windows is an *implementation that produces slow code*. I'd start by rebuilding the lot (including the SQLite3 library) *with full optimisations enabled*. Following that, you could try using a profiler to determine where the difference is and use the results to perform intelligent optimisations to your code.

Comment: It could even be the I/O performed by sqlite that's different on the platforms, and nothing directly related to the sqlite code or the program.

Comment: @nos Indeed. That'd hopefully be highlighted by profiling on Linux and Windows to determine where the difference in *speed* lies. If SQLite3 is faster on Linux than on Windows, there isn't much that can be done aside from rebuilding the lot with full optimisations enabled and testing again, or replacing it with a different SQL engine.